# How to get free time in a list of booking rooms have been booked using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I working database and i have a problem when i calculate time available booking room in hotel

My table look like

Room:

```
 _________________________________________________________________
| roomid  | roomname  | type      | time_start  | time_end        |
|_________|___________|___________|_____________|_________________|
|  R01    |  Room1    |     1     |  07:00      |    07:30        |
|_________|___________|___________|_____________|_________________|
|  R01    |  Room1    |     2     |  08:30      |    9:30         |
|_________|___________|___________|_____________|_________________|
|  R02    |  Room2     |   3      |  7:30       |   8:15          |    
|_________|___________|___________|_____________|_________________|
|  R02    |  Room2    |  4        |  10:15      |   11:20         |
|_________|___________|___________|_____________|_________________|
```

I have a start time and duration booking room. I want return time_start and time_end available user can booking room.
Example: I want query in database and choice time almost time of user input and duration free time must >=30. User want booking begin 8:00 and booking duration 30 minute. In my database , you can see I have two booking room. Room 01 booking 7:00 -> 7h:30 and 8:30 ->9:30 it mean room1 available 7h31 -> 8:29. Room 02 booking 7:30 -> 8:15 and 10:15 ->11:20 it mean room1 available 8:16 -> 10:14.

I have two room user can booking:

```
1 . Room01:   7h31 -> 8:29

2. Room02: 8:16 -> 10:14
```

because condition is that the booking time is closest to the user input time and the booking time must be greater than or equal to 30. It mean :
I choice room1 user can booking and i want return time available user can booking(7h31 -> 8:29).
If user booking room at 5:00:00 but in my booking table the time starts from 7:00:00 and ends at 11:00:00, I would like to take the booking time of the user and The end time will be 5:00:00. I wish the query returned would be start_time: 5:00:00 and end_time: 5:30:00. How do I do that?

I try write sql code look like

```
SELECT r.start_time, r.end_time
FROM rooms r
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT room_id, r.time_start - r.end_time > :input_time)
    FROM r
    GROUP BY room_id
  ) r1
  ON b1.room_id = b.room_id
```

But i think it not work.

I have a question. How to return time_start and time_end available user can booking room with condition booking time is closest to the user input time and the booking time must be greater than or equal to 30 if i have start_time and list booking room.
If user booking room at 5:00:00 but in my booking table the time starts from 7:00:00 and ends at 11:00:00, I would like to take the booking time of the user and The end time will be 5:00:00. I wish the query returned would be time_start: 5:00:00 and time_end: 5:30:00. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh i using Postgresql

Comment: Rooms by the hour... For what kind of activity?!?

Comment: Example : You booking hotel or something and you only want booking specific time. You want booking begin 8:00 and you only booking 30 minutes. You only booking in day. If any room free time in day, you can booking it if condition time free >30 minutes. If there are 2 empty rooms in 2 different time periods. You choose the room with the time closest to your booking time

Comment: Why are the room_ids do not fit to room names?

Comment: @S-Man I had fix it.

Answer (score 0):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=134078b2283bf7cdc7e368058d7f7826)

Using the lag() [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) gives you the expected result:

```
SELECT
    room_id,
    last_time + interval '1 minute' AS free_time_start,
    time_start - interval '1 minute' AS free_time_end
FROM (
    SELECT
        lag(time_end) OVER (PARTITION BY room_id ORDER BY time_start) AS last_time,
        *
    FROM
        rooms
) s
WHERE last_time < time_start
```

The window function allows you to get a value from the previous record (you can group it on room_id with the `PARTITION BY` clause and have to add a certain order).

The free time exists if the previous end time is smaller than the current start time.

---

Adding the booking time:

You can take the booking time and check whether it fits into the calculated free time. After that you can order by the fitting slots and give out only the first result using `LIMIT`

```
SELECT
    free_time_start,
    free_time_end,
    booking_start BETWEEN free_time_start AND free_time_end
        AND 
    booking_end BETWEEN free_time_start AND free_time_end
FROM (
    SELECT
        room_id,
        last_time + interval '1 minute' AS free_time_start,
        time_start - interval '1 minute' AS free_time_end,
        '08:00'::time AS booking_start,
        '08:00'::time + interval '29 minutes' AS booking_end
    FROM (
        SELECT
            lag(time_end) OVER (PARTITION BY room_id ORDER BY time_start) AS last_time,
            *
        FROM
            rooms
    ) s
    WHERE last_time < time_start
) s
ORDER BY 3 DESC, 1
LIMIT 1
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3b26a2563390554f59ee9f8a53fd43e6)

Comment: Thanks you very much. But how to i return only time 07:31:00 08:29:00 . because booking 1 has the closest time to the time the user entered and I want to return its start and time

Comment: The problem here is that the booking you are searching for is 8:00 to 8:30. The last minute won't fit into the range... What should the query do?

Comment: If the query does not fit the scope. It will continue to search for rooms and other times. If there is only 1 room, it will choose. If there are 2 rooms that match the scope. It will return the time close to the time of the most user input

Comment: If it is assumed that it fits within that range. How can I return time close to the time of user input.

Comment: Added a simple check for fitting times assuming the booking range would fit (it is only 29 minutes long). But finding a non fitting slot that is some kind of close would lead in extremely nasty algorithms since there are too many parameters to be checked. This would be something that I really not recommend to do within the database.

Comment: Many thanks for the help. Initially I intended to implement it by sql. Since I am using Java to transmit list room and user booking time to sql. If I use one to pass a list of rooms from java I will put it in sql as a param

Comment: Suppose the user booking room at 5:00:00 but in my booking table the time starts from 7:00:00 and ends at 7:30:00, I would like to take the booking time of the user and The end time will be 7:00:00. I wish the query returned would be start_time: 5:00:00 and end_time: 5:30:00. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If user input before time when booking room ?